# Receiver not getting data

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

so my receiver is working fine...pending intents are being sent and received and all was working fine until this...i have a spinner containing alarm sounds and when the user clicks on an item in it, i want to get the position and send it to the receiver..problem is the receiver always gets the value as 0..can someone help

This is my spinner in my alarm clock activity

```
int choose_alarm_sound;

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                choose_alarm_sound = position;
                Intent broad_Intent = new Intent();
                Log.e("TEST 1", choose_alarm_sound + "");



                switch (selected) {
                    case "Buzzer": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.buzzer);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Doorbell": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.doorbell);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case "FirePager": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.firepager);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Ring": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.ring);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case "SchoolBell": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.schoolbell);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Siren": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.siren);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Siren2": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.siren2);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case "SmokeAlarm": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.smokealarm);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case "Warning": {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(alarmClockActivity.this, R.raw.warning);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    }

                }
                broad_Intent.putExtra("alarm_choice", choose_alarm_sound);
                Log.e("TEST 2", choose_alarm_sound + "");
                sendBroadcast(broad_Intent);
```

and this is my receiver

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    Integer getAlarm=arg1.getExtras().getInt("alarm_choice");

    Log.e("TEST 3", String.valueOf(getAlarm));
```

}

so my logs test 1 and test 2 always have the same value which is the right value, but test 3 in receiver is 0 every single time..so my receiver isnt receiving this intent..why...any help would be greatly appreciated

manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/mini"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TimeDateRem"/>
    <activity android:name=".BirthdayRem"/>
    <activity android:name=".Details"/>
    <activity android:name=".DailyReminder"/>
    <activity android:name=".HolidayReminderLebanon"/>
    <activity android:name=".HolidayReminderSaudiArabia"/>
    <activity android:name=".HolidayReminderKuwait"/>
    <activity android:name=".HolidayReminderUAE"/>
    <activity android:name=".AlarmChooser"/>
    <activity android:name=".Timer"/>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
</receiver>
    <service android:name=".MediaPlayingService"/>
</application>
```

Comment: In the code you've posted, you never put **anything** in `broad-Intent` other than the extra. When you call `sendBroadcast()` nothing should happen, because there is no ACTION or component set in the broadcast `Intent`. Your `AlarmReceiver.onReceive()` should never get called. Please edit your post to reflect the actual code you are using!

Comment: so what if i dont...it should be sent either way shouldnt it? the rest of my code has nothing to do with this part...this specific intent is supposed to get me the position of the item in the spinner to the receiver...so if sendbroadcast wont do it with just an extra in the intent...how am i supposed to send that intent to the receiver? and the receiver is being called...the log (test 3) in my receiver is being called but is returning 0 which is not the correct value @DavidWasser

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense at all. If you send a broadcast `Intent` with just an "extra", Android has no idea who to deliver the `Intent` to. Broadcast `Intent`s are system-wide and Android will dispatch the `Intent` to all listeners who register to receive it. In my opinion, something else is causing your `AlarmReceiver.onReceive()` to be called, which would explain why the "extra" is not in the `Intent` where you expect it to be. Please post your manifest, maybe that will help solve this mystery!

Comment: but doesnt send broadcast only send to the broadcast receiver? in my case i only have one receiver and that means the intent should only be deivered to my AlarmReceiver.class ...this is really bugging me i havent been able to fix this for a while now and i have a due in a few hours... @DavidWasser

Comment: No. When you send a broadcast `Intent`, Android delivers it to all registered listeners. The listeners need to indicate what kind of broadcast `Intent` they are interested in. Listeners do this by specifying an `Intent` filter (either programatically or in the manifest). I see that you have not specified an `<intent-filter>` for `AlarmReceiver` in the manifest. Therefore, there is no way that `AlarmReceiver` is getting triggered unless you have programatically registered it as a listener. Have you called `registerReceiver()` anywhere? Please post the relevant code!

Comment: first of all thank you for bearing with me...second i thought <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
</receiver> qualifies as registring the receiver... if it doesnt please tell me how  i should do that ...i have not called registerReceiver..and thank you again @DavidWasser

Comment: I was just going to bed ;-) I'll add an answer with code examples in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting `choose_alarm_sound` to `id` and not `position`.

Comment: not really..i just set it to position and the receiver still gets the value as 0 @Marc

Comment: As your code is now in your post, yes really, you are setting choose_alarm_sound to id, which you cast from long to int, instead of using the actual spinner position. Change choose_alarm_sound to an integer (it is written as a long in your code), change choose_alarm_sound = (int)id; to choose_alarm_sound = position;  and it'll work

Comment: i just did that... test 3 is still 0 which means the receiver still hasnt received that value correctly.. @Marc

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to tell you. If your receiver is firing it doesn't make sense to me that the intent isn't null, but also doesn't have your value.

Comment: Is this receiver registered in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: yes it is..its working fine my alarms are being received and all is working except for this piece of code and i just cant seem to figure out what is wrong... @Marc

Comment: I don't know. Something is wrong. I feel like there's something you may not be showing (not necessarily on purpose). Very fishy. Sorry, but I don't know how to help anymore. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the broadcast `Intent` with an ACTION and you need to tell Android to call your `BroadcastReceiver` when it sees that ACTION. Try something like this:

In manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="MyAlarmReceiver"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This tells Android to call `AlarmReceiver.onReceive()` if anyone sends a broadcast `Intent` where the ACTION is "MyAlarmReceiver".

Now, when you create the broadcast `Intent` in `onItemSelected()`, do this:

```
Intent broad_Intent = new Intent("MyAlarmReceiver");
```

This sets the ACTION in the broadcast `Intent` to "MyAlarmReceiver".

Comment: i was so sure this would work..it didnt..same output...test 3 is still 0 ...thank you anyway

Comment: what i realised is that after adding this code the receiver is being called twice...so it was already being called

Comment: If AlarmReceiver is already being called then you must have registered it somewhere! Please scan your code for references to AlarmReceiver. Otherwise this makes no sense at all!

Comment: In your original post, you claim that _"my receiver is working fine...pending intents are being sent and received"_ This would imply that you are using `AlarmReceiver` somewhere else in code. Please post that code.